# Cannot be selected newly inserted rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

my problem is that I've been trying to insert new records by simply getting the max of the primary key of the table then add it by 1, my previous max is 100152, all is well when I insert it once, however, when I try to insert new record, I get an error saying that I'm inserting a duplicate. I later found out that, even if I already inserted a row with primary key 100153, the max id I get from it is still 100152. I know that 100153 record exist, but why can't I select it as if it doesn't exists? Is this hidden or something? Thanks in advance to those who will answer, I'm really confused here.

Comment: if 2 different sessions are doing this logic concurrently (get max instead of just using a sequence), then 1 of the sessions is going to fail.  Any reason you aren't using a sequence for this?

Comment: When and how you calculate your `MAX`?  Is it a part of your `INSERT` statement?

Comment: I already changed the mechanism and used the sequence instead but still newly inserted rows cannot be seen if queried using a select statement,  are these rows somehow hidden?

Answer (score 1):

I can assume, you have two concurrent sessions:

Let's create a table and insert into it the first row:

Session1:

```
SQL> conn scott 
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> create table ttt ( 
  2    col1 number(10) primary key
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into ttt values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;
```

Session2:

```
SQL> conn scott
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> select * from ttt;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from ttt;

      COL1
----------
         1
```

Let's use the max value of the `ttt` table to generate the primary key value for next value:

Session1:

```
SQL> insert into ttt select max(col1) + 1 from ttt;

1 row created.
```

Session2:

```
SQL> insert into ttt select max(col1) + 1 from ttt;
```

Session2 hangs, because it is blocked by Session1.

Let's commit the session1:

Session1:

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

I can see this in the Session2:

```
SQL> insert into ttt select max(col1) + 1 from ttt;
insert into ttt select max(col1) + 1 from ttt
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C0010855) violated

SQL> select * from ttt;

      COL1
----------
         1
         2
```

So it is a bad idea to generate next value of primary key using current max value. For this purposes you have to create a sequence:

Session1:

```
SQL> create sequence ttt_pk_seq
  2  start with 3
  3  /

Sequence created.

SQL> insert into ttt values (ttt_pk_seq.nextval);

1 row created.
```

Session2:

```
SQL> insert into ttt values (ttt_pk_seq.nextval);

1 row created.
```

Session1:

```
SQL> commit;
```

Session2:

```
SQL> select * from ttt;

      COL1
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
```

It is possible, because work with sequences is always performed in the autonomous transaction.

P.S.: To increase your app's performance use a [reverse key index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1181) for the primary key

Comment: Hi sir @zaratustra thanks for you answer and sorry for this late reply, I did what you suggested here and somehow it did solve my problem, however, I still cant search for this newly inserted data, I can now insert without worrying for the unique constraint violated error, however, due to the newly inserted rows, being 'invisible', I ended up adding same data though with unique IDs, but they are still duplicates. Why do you think this is possible sir?

Comment: First of all, I assume, you don't commit you changes that why you can't see new rows. Secondly, what are you calling "duplicates"? What columns have to be the same to conclude that the rows are duplicates?

Comment: Actually, autocommit is set to true after the sql statements, however just to be sure, I also checked what is the default value of autocommit before the statements and it is also set to true, so I dont think its the commit that caused it. Also, 'duplicates' exist because knowing that the newly inserted rows cannot be selected or is 'invisible', even if that data already exist, it is unknown to the program thus, causing every operation to be an insert instead of an update operation for supposedly existing data. Hope you got my point, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

A better design approach is to use Trigger and Sequence to auto Increment the value of the Row. 
Sequence example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE ACCOUNT_SEQ 
 START WITH 1 -- for you case start with the maximum value of the column value
 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Trigger Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1
BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNTS -- tablename 
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (new.ID IS NULL)  -- column name of the table
BEGIN
  SELECT ACCOUNTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :new.ID
  FROM dual;
END;
/
```